# Incomplete MYSQL Dumps

Tags: mysqldump

I am using MySQL dump to back up my MySQL Databases and I'm having trouble with a couple dumps on one box.

> **Server Specs**
>
> Windows 2008
>
> MySQL 5.1.48-community

I've tried various parameters in the `mysqldump` command and not much seems to help.

```
mysqldump --user=%mysqluser% --password=%mysqlpassword% --max_allowed_packet=64M \n 
    INSERTDBNAMEHERE INSERTTABLENAMEHERE > %basedir%\export.sql
```

What is odd, is if I do a dump out of `phpmyadmin`, it is fine.

Comment: Are the missing objects the same between tries?

Comment: Is the dump file always 2Gb or 4Gb in size?

Comment: @dezo - it stops at the same point between tries

Comment: @Phil it is not anywhere near 2 or 4 gb

Comment: I've still had no luck with this any more ideas?

Comment: I've tried different flags int he mysqldump command without much luck. I tried quick and verbose and nothing seems to stand out. If I run the same dump many times, it yields the same results each time. I'm wondering if I need to change my mysql config file.

Answer (score 1):

Use the -v (or --verbose) option for mysqdump which can show the errors that occur